# SQlite database SELECT EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION code EXC_I386_INVOP subcode 0x0

Tags: xcode, swift, sqlite

I am trying to run simple query using any available sqlite library and swift language in iOS project.

This is the code I have (commented out version was implementation of another library, it throws the same error which implies the problem is with underlying sqlite implementation) :

Libraries used: 
 (commented out version) SQLite.swift
 (uncommented version) SQLiteDB
    var values = [""]

```
let dbQueue = try! DatabaseQueue(path: dbPath + "/database.db")
        dbQueue.inDatabase { db in

            let ratedMotorPowers = String.fetchAll(db, "select ratedMotorPower_kW from msc_sku_data_008_live2") // [String]
        }
//        let db = try! Connection(dbPath + "/configurator.db")
//        
//        for row in try! db.prepare("select id from msc_sku_data_008_live2") {
//            print("id: \(row[1])")
//            values.append(String(row[1]))
//            // id: 1, email: alice@mac.com, name: Optional("Alice")
//        }

        return values
```

The error thrown is EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION code EXC_I386_INVOP subcode 0x0

The error gets thrown on the line with query: String.fetchAll

Comment: Are you using multiple threads ?

Comment: no, I am using one thread with one simple query

Comment: Use `try` Instead of `try!`. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes, I am getting errors and I have described it at the end of post. When I am using try instead of try! I have to swallow the exception because I have not found a way to catch and print the exception message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

The problem turned out to be in database path.

The magical formula that I have seen in many tutorials did not work:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
```

This one works and this was the path where my database resource was located:

```
var resourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!
```